# Can't unprotect an excel worksheet in Workbook_BeforeSave

Tags: excel, vba

I am using Workbook_BeforeSave to update some cells on a locked sheet in excel 2010. The subroutine works as desired when using ctrl-s to save, but will not unlock the sheet when using .Save in vba.

ThisWorkbook(code)

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim MyPassword As String
    MyPassword = "password"

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Unprotect (MyPassword)

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = Now
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value = ThisWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Author")

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Protect (MyPassword)
End Sub
```

Module1(Code)

```
Sub SaveMe()
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

I have a button that calls SaveMe(). SaveMe() saves the document, activating Workbook_BeforeSave. The Worsheet fails to unprotect, causing an error when writing to A1.

The error states:

```
Run-time error '1004':
Application-defined or object-defined error
```

Comment: Why not use `ThisWorkbook` inplace of `ActiveWorkbook` ? If you're operating on the workbook which contains the code, then `ThisWorkbook` is safer...

Comment: I've tried both. In my actual project I am using Thisworkbook.

Comment: "Application-defined or object-defined error" is what you get when a VBA error occurs, but you don't have any error-handling.  Add an error-handler to the failing routine and have it display a MsgBox with the actual VBA error number and description.

Comment: RBarryYoung - I don't understand what you mean. I tried: MsgBox Err & ": " & Error(Err). That gave me the same error number and message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me, but it is not very elegant. I did not find a separate module for both unprotecting and writing worked.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    UnlockWorksheets
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        .Range("A1").Value = Now
        .Range("A2").Value = ThisWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Author")
    End With
    LockWorksheets
End Sub

Sub SaveMe()
    UnlockWorksheets
    ThisWorkbook.Save
    LockWorksheets
End Sub

Sub UnlockWorksheets()
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Unprotect Password:="password"
End Sub

Sub LockWorksheets()
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Protect Password:="password"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried something similar but forgot to set the variable MyPassword. Do you know why Workbook_BeforeSave does will not unlock the sheet?

Answer (score 0):

why not put the 'before save' module into a new sub routine and have the before close call that

EG.

```
    Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
 Call SomeSub
End Sub

sub someSub()
'Code here
end sub

sub Button()
call SomeCub
activeworkbook.save
end sub
```

Comment: I tried the code you suggested and it works correctly on the button press but fails on the second call of someSub by Workbook_BeforeSave.